# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, androidx

**Вот такая ошибка вылазит при раздутии xml-макета на версиях Андроид ниже Lolipop:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{AuthenticationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at ru.tehnomaks.carpark.Activity.Client.AuthenticationActivity.onCreate(AuthenticationActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at ru.tehnomaks.carpark.Activity.Client.AuthenticationActivity.onCreate(AuthenticationActivity.java:31) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_auth_phone.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07007a
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1928)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:628)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:58)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.<init>(TextInputEditText.java:48)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.<init>(TextInputEditText.java:44)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at ru.tehnomaks.carpark.Activity.Client.AuthenticationActivity.onCreate(AuthenticationActivity.java:31) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:863)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
```

**Разметка:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/auth_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        tools:context=".Activity.Client.AuthenticationActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/auth_edit_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_auth_phone"
                    android:hint="Телефон"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_default"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/auth_edit_pass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_auth_lock"
                    android:hint="Пароль"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_default"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/auth_tv_registration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/auth_tv_registration"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_tvRememberPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/auth_tv_rememberPass"
                android:textColor="@color/auth_tv_remember_pass"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/main_btnInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/auth_btn_input"
                android:textColor="@color/btn_text_default"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent2"
                app:cornerRadius="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auth_tv_registration"
                app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**Зависимости**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Comment: вот такая же проблема, есть куча способов в ответах, может что-то подойдет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957275/inflateexception-when-using-textinputlayout .

Comment: Там проблема с TextInputLayout, а у меня с TextInputEditText. И я все испробовал, что там написано)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно сообщению об ошибке `invalid drawable tag vector` у вас в иконке `ic_auth_phone.xml` есть какой-то xml-тэг нераспознаваемый системой. Такое происходит из-за ограничений 5- андроида в части распознавания векторных изображений. Вариантов решения 3:

1. Пойти к дизайнерам и просить их перерисовывать иконку пока она не заработает.
2. Заменить формат иконки на `png`. Можно, в т.ч. только для ОС < 5 версии.
3. Поставить минимальную версию ОС >= 5.